# what's the difference between apache gobblin and spring-cloud-dataflow, how to choose?

Tags: bigdata, etl, data-ingestion, gobblin

As the official documentation

> Apache Gobblin is a universal data ingestion framework for extracting, transforming, and loading large volume of data from a variety of data sources, e.g., databases, rest APIs, FTP/SFTP servers, filers, etc., onto Hadoop.
>
> Spring Cloud Data Flow is a toolkit for building data integration and real-time data processing pipelines.Pipelines consist of Spring Boot apps, built using the Spring Cloud Stream or Spring Cloud Task microservice frameworks.

1. what's difference between them?
2. what's the advance each other?
3. How do I choose them in the corresponding scenario?

Thank very much for any reply